# Extract string conditional on set of predefined characters

Tags: r, string, character, stringr

I'm using R 3.5 and RStudio.

I have the following vector of characters as well as a predefined set of characters (another vector). I want to use the predefined set to extract the characters from the vector irregardless of the order of characters in the predefined set.

The MWE:

```
ranchar <- c("rtrt, ABC","DEF, ktg", "eeh ABC HuJ","hJN, DEF, Jjk","hJN, DEF, Jjk")    
set <- c("ABC","DEF")
```

The result I want would be a vector or list such as

```
[1] "ABC" "DEF" "ABC" "DEF" "DEF"
```

However, using str_extract_all from the stringr package results in

```
 library(stringr)
 str_extract_all(ranchar, set)
 [[1]]
 [1] "ABC"

 [[2]]
[1] "DEF"

[[3]]
[1] "ABC"

[[4]]
[1] "DEF"

[[5]]
character(0)
```

Apparently, the order of the characters in the object "set" is important (see fifth element). However, I want the function to simply extract the characters from the vector ranchar without caring about the order of characters in ranchar or the set.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how `str_extract_all` works. The function is vectorised over both arguments. Since your two vectors have different lengths, **R implicitly recycles `set` to match the length of `ranchar`**. That means that for the fifth element of `ranchar` `str_extract_all` will try to match `"ABC"`.

Comment: You say *"characters from the vector"* but really mean strings, right? Or is `"BAC"` equivalent to `"ABC"`?

Comment: Additionally: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. What do you expect to happen to a string `"rtrt, ABC, DEF"`. Will it return `"ABC"` or `"DEF"` or both or none?

Comment: @MauritsEvers: I think I have an idea how      str_extract_all     works. But thank you, haven't thought about the case of multiple of predefined strings of set occurring in the "target" vector. I have added a comment to G5W's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the `pattern` argument to `str_extract` be `set`, you need to turn it into a regular expression that allows any one of the elements of the set.

```
str_extract(ranchar, paste0(set, collapse="|"))
"ABC" "DEF" "ABC" "DEF" "DEF"
```

The pattern is:

```
paste0(set, collapse="|")
[1] "ABC|DEF"
```

which allows "ABC" or "DEF"

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. Related to Maurits Evers's question: Is there a way to get only the first or last element if a string has      "rtrt, ABC, DEF"? If not, I just use a workaround.